# “Wake on network access” not working

Tags: macos, network

Brand new M2 Mac mini connected to my LAN via wired Ethernet. Latest OS. “Wake for network activity” is enabled.
It doesn’t wake, for example as target for web service (MAMP), or anything else I can think to try. I have to physically wake it up.

Comment: This is an old problem that appears to never have been properly fixed: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/435148/wake-up-a-sleeping-or-powered-off-m1-mac-mini-with-a-wake-on-lan-packet

Comment: This is exactly the same issue as described here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/461244/119271

Comment: Also, I wouldn’t use a MacBook as a server.  Use a cheap computer instead.  Even an RPi would be a better fit.

Comment: The new mini is to replace a 2009 mini that has served all my server needs just fine for lo these many years. It's also used as a desktop client.

Comment: @Allan No, it's not. That was about a USB Ethernet adapter. My mini's Ethernet interface is built in.

Comment: You’re correct.  I mis-read the “mini” part.  There was no close vote though.  However, WoL is flaky at best.  Because it operates at layer 2 (OSI model), there are a ton of variables like whether or not your switch supports it, if the address table stays in memory, etc.  If you need something to wake your mini up, look for something out-of-band like a console over ethernet interface from Lantronix.